# Reading Facebook Events from API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

Having a problem with the Facebook Javascript SDK.

I would like to get a list of all events linked to a particular page.

So far I have had limited success.

I am able to retrieve data for current or upcoming events, but I would like to retrieve past events as well.

The facebook page that I am interested in getting events for is:
https://www.facebook.com/TRUTH.Jhb/events?key=past

So far I have tried the following [FQL Statement](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/?method=GET&path=fql%3Fq%3DSELECT%20eid%2C%20name%20FROM%20event%20WHERE%20eid%20IN%20%28SELECT%20eid%20FROM%20event_member%20WHERE%20uid%20%3D%2079431685972%29%20AND%20start_time%20%3C%200)

But this query returns an empty result.

Can you please help me, there is obviously something I am missing

Thanks in advance

Wez

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved. The nested select statement reads from the event_member table, this table only returns current events by default.

You have to set a start_time condition inside this statement such as:

SELECT eid, name FROM event WHERE eid IN (SELECT eid FROM event_member WHERE uid = 79431685972  AND **start_time > 0**)

this effectively returns past as well as current events